# Direct sum of infinite dimensional vector space for idempotent operator

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

I know for linear operator $T$ on finite dimensional space $V$ such that $T^2=T$, we have $V=R(T)\oplus N(T)$, but does the result hold true for infinite dimensional spaces also? I tried to find counterexample but couldn't find. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: True, and the proof is same whether the space is f.d. or not: $x=Tx+(x-Tx)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm your comment looks like an answer to me

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you. Actually I had a different proof which was using the fact that space was finite dimensional.